# How to use the PHP template engine in Twig instead of the Twig syntax within Silex

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

In Silex I am able to use Twig templates but I want to use the PHP engine of Twig, instead of the Twig syntax. For example [this guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html) describes how to do it for Symfony but not Silex.

My Silex `index.php` looks like:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',
));

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html.php', array(
        'name' => 'Bob',
    ));
});
```

My `index.html.php` looks like:

```
<p>Welcome to the index <?php echo $view->name; ?></p>
```

When I run the app in the browser and view the source, I see the literal string `<?php echo $view->name; ?>` which hasn't been executed.

I suspect there may be a Twig config setting to tell it I want to use the PHP style templates. To clarify, if I use the Twig syntax instead, e.g.:

```
<p>Welcome to the index {{ name }} </p>
```

Then it works and I see the name `Bob`, therefore I know this is not a web server or PHP config problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to mimic this behaviour in Silex, you would need to install the TwigBridge via Composer. Then build the `templating` service the same way Symfony does.

This solution works as I have tested it successfully.

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\PhpEngine;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateNameParser;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\Loader\FilesystemLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\DelegatingEngine;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine;

$app = new Application();

$app['debug'] = true;

// Register Twig

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',
));


// Build the templating service

$app['templating.engines'] = $app->share(function() {
    return array(
        'twig',
        'php'
    );
});

$app['templating.loader'] = $app->share(function() {
    return new FilesystemLoader(__DIR__.'/views/%name%');
});

$app['templating.template_name_parser'] = $app->share(function() {
    return new TemplateNameParser();
});

$app['templating.engine.php'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    return new PhpEngine($app['templating.template_name_parser'], $app['templating.loader']);
});

$app['templating.engine.twig'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    return new TwigEngine($app['twig'], $app['templating.template_name_parser']);
});

$app['templating'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    $engines = array();

    foreach ($app['templating.engines'] as $i => $engine) {
        if (is_string($engine)) {
            $engines[$i] = $app[sprintf('templating.engine.%s', $engine)];
        }
    }

    return new DelegatingEngine($engines);
});


// Render controllers

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app['templating']->render('hello.html.twig', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
});

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($name) use ($app) {
    return $app['templating']->render('hello.html.php', array('name' => $name));
});

$app->run();
```

You would need at least these dependencies to achieve this in your composer.json

```
"require": {
    "silex/silex": "~1.0",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.0",
    "symfony/templating": "~2.0",
    "twig/twig": "~1.0"
},
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the detailed answer. Is it possible to manually copy the necessary files instead of using Composer?

Comment: @ServerBloke np, Composer will do it for you. I've added what you would need in your composer.json to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, accepted your answer. Will Composer just pull the files I need into the project? I'm not familiar with it but will look into it if it's better than manually copying the files.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! I wrapped it in it's own ServiceProvider and set an $app['root.views'] path to globally configure where the templates are.