# How to use the PHP template engine in Twig instead of the Twig syntax within Silex 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

In Silex2 I am able to use Twig templates but I want to use the PHP engine of Twig, instead of the Twig syntax. For example [this guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html) describes how to do it for Symfony but not **Silex 2**.

My Silex `index.php` looks like:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',
));

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html.php', array(
        'name' => 'Bob',
    ));
});
```

My `index.html.php` looks like:

```
<p>Welcome to the index <?php echo $view->name; ?></p>
```

When I run the app in the browser and view the source, I see the literal string `<?php echo $view->name; ?>` which hasn't been executed.

I suspect there may be a Twig config setting to tell it I want to use the PHP style templates. To clarify, if I use the Twig syntax instead, e.g.:

```
<p>Welcome to the index {{ name }} </p>
```

Then it works and I see the name Bob, therefore I know this is not a web server or PHP config problem.

This code didnt work for me:

```
$app['template'] = function($app) use($settings) {
    $loader = new \Symfony\Component\Templating\Loader\FilesystemLoader([
        BASE_DIR . $settings->templates_path
    ]);
    $nameParser = new \Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateNameParser();
    $templating = new \Symfony\Component\Templating\PhpEngine($nameParser, $loader);
    return $templating;
};
```

though, this is didnt work too:

```
$app->register(new NS\ViewServiceProvider(), [
    'view.path' => BASE_DIR . $settings->templates_path,
]);
```

`ViewServiceProvider`:

```
class ViewServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Container $app)
    {
        $app['view'] = function($app) {
            $engine  = $app['view.engine'];
            $helpers = isset($app['view.helpers']) ? $app['view.helpers'] : array();
            $helpers = array_merge($helpers, $app['view.default_helpers']);
            $engine->setHelpers($helpers);
            return $engine;
        };
        $app['view.engine'] = function($app) {
            return new PhpEngine($app['view.parser'], $app['view.loader']);
        };
        $app['view.loader'] = function($app) {
            $paths = isset($app['view.path']) ? $app['view.path'] : array();
            return new FileSystemLoader($paths);
        };
        $app['view.parser'] = function() {
            return new TemplateNameParser;
        };
        $app['view.default_helpers'] = function() {
            return array(
                new \Symfony\Component\Templating\Helper\SlotsHelper
            );
        };
    }
}
```

Both throws an error, that cannot find the `view.php` file

Comment: Here is how twig is registered in Silex : http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/twig.html you can deregister it if you don't want to use it. Actually I'm curious to know why you prefer to write `<?php echo $view->name; ?>` instead of `{{ name }}` ? it's so much easier !

Comment: As you can see in Silex [included providers](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers.html#included-providers), the [Templating component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/templating.html) is not built-in. You'll need to [create your own ServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers.html#creating-a-provider).

Comment: @mickdev If you don't want to use Twig you don't need to "deregister" it, you just won't register it. It's not enabled by default. Also, as pointed out, Twig does not have a "PHP engine", Twig **is** a templating engine, if you don't want to use it and prefer to use the [PHP Templating Engine Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/templating.html), you need to create a [service provider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers.html) for it and register it (like you can do with the out of the box Twig provider). PS: I would not follow that route...

Comment: @mTorres I think we are talking about the same thing, the way we are saying it is just different. Anyway, Alain Tiembo has already 'translate' what I was thinking in the first place.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22253207/209585) might help.

Comment: @mickdev damn, I  tried to do that thing (registering this service provider) but had not came to the right decision and was hoping on exact code.. =(

Comment: this code does not work too:
`$app['template'] = function($app) use($settings) {
  $loader = new \Symfony\Component\Templating\Loader\FilesystemLoader([
   BASE_DIR . $settings->templates_path
  ]);
  $nameParser = new \Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateNameParser();
  $templating = new \Symfony\Component\Templating\PhpEngine($nameParser, $loader);
  return $templating;
 };`